show image not an icon in panel?
what if its not a square icon ? (eg. 120x300px) image I wanna show in panel. possible ?
I am working on displaying an image in a panel, but I have a specific use case where the image is not a square icon. For example, consider an image with dimensions like non-square (ie 120x300px..) pixels—a tall rectangle rather than a typical square icon.
